Multiple Passwords for Multiple Schemas in single connection
I'm using DBeaver as my DB manager, I'm trying to make a connection to oracleDB with multiple schema's and each schema with it's own username/passord.
I want to know is there a way to configure these multiple username/passwords for these schema's in a single DB connection?
e.g:
connection to DB example

example:
 Schema
   sc1 - connect to this  
   sc2 - connect to this as well
    .
    .
    .
   scn - and this


I am not sure that I follow the question.  A database connection is made as a single user.  That user may have access to multiple schemas.  You either want to configure multiple connections in your GUI or you want to configure a single connection in the GUI and manage permissions appropriately in the database.

No. You can't.
Database connections are tightly connected with Users. You need to create multiple connections with different different username and passwords. I can feel your pain but it is not possible. I am also using multiple databases for multiple applications and environments within single database server. For security purpose staging and production users are different and app users are also different.
Short way is: Use can create new user who have access of all those Databases but it is not recommended for all team members.

that's just very bad way to go

True. That's why I am not recommended that for all.
